# Probability the two red were from factory A

Tags: probability

Factory A makes 40% red widgets and 60% black widgets. Factory B makes 30% red widgets and 70% black widgets. Two widgets are sampled at random from one of the companies, also selected at random They are both red. What is the probability that it was Factory A?

Please someone let me know if my solution is correct.
$$P(redred|A) = 0.4 * 0.4 = 0.16$$
$$P(redred|B) = 0.3 * 0.3 = 0.09$$

$$P(A|redred) = \frac{P(redred|A)*P(A)}{P(redred)} = \frac{P(redred|A) * P(A)}{P(redred|A) * P(A) + P(redred|B) * P(B)}$$
$$P(A|redred) =\frac{0.16 * 0.5}{0.16 * 0.5 + 0.09 * 0.5} = 0.64$$

So the probability that the two red widgets are from factory A is 64%

If this solution is wrong, Please give me the correct way to solve it.

Comment: It is the right answer

Comment: @trueblueanil Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: You're welcome !